# How to make a condition in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have such a situation, I need to execute my function each time the string searchTerms **and** total.value is changing.
Here is how it looks like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {      
        total_results: data?.hits.total.value,
        error_message: null,
      });
    }
  }, [data?.hits.total.value && searchTerms]);
```

But it works not as expected, I need to execute this function only when data.hits.total.value && searchTerms is changed. Not OR!

If I will make it like this

```
[data?.hits.total.value, searchTerms]
```

Then my function would log 2 times each search, but I don't need it.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The dependencies should be separated by a comma (`,`). See [`useEffect` usage](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect)

Comment: the syntax seems right you have to check if either of them is undefined in the console.

Comment: @ShivamJha I already wrote that i I will put comma the my function logs 2 times each search. I need only 1 time

Comment: If you are using React 18,It logs twice only in development. It should not bother you as it will log only once in prod. See [useEffect firing twice in development](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development).

If you are not using React 18, and still firing twice, then you need to reconsider your approach. (Make sure your linter is not showing any warning in `useEffect`)

Comment: how is this "dupe" related to OPs problem that he wants the effect only to fire after ALL deps have changed? Not when any single one of them has changed.,

Comment: @Thomas Thanks you got me right, how can I check it, any advice?

Comment: I'd write a hook that extends useEffect by a function that determines if the current deps are different (enough) from the previously accepted ones. But if you want to do it right, that's a bit more than a oneliner. You have to keep track of the previous deps array and you have to manage the cleanup function manually.

Comment: I guess, I'm thinking too general purpose, for this explicit case, this should do: `const ref = useRef([]), deps = [data?.hits.total.value, searchTerms]; useEffect(() => { if (deps.every((v, i) => v !== ref.current[i])) { ref.current = deps;    /*...*/ } }, deps);`

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, but it is still don't call the function when the data?.hits.total.value is the same as the previous one :(

Comment: That's what you wanted (untill now). Then you have to change the condition to something that describes what you mean, because what you said was "when all deps have changed". `ref.current` contains the last deps that were logged, `deps` contains the current ones. Now it's up to you to create a condition that describes what the difference between the two has to be so that you want to log again.

Comment: @Thomas thank you sm! One more question, how can I take last value of data?.hits.total.value from deps?

Comment: `ref.current[0]`